# How can I respawn the object again after player collides with it?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to respawn object at a new position immediately after player collides with it.
For now my code just spawn the object after respawn time and destroy the previous object.
The code on my empty object on unity2d is

```
    public GameObject point;
private Vector2 screenBounds;
public float respawnTime = 10f;
GameObject star;
void Start()
{
    screenBounds = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Screen.width, Screen.height, Camera.main.transform.position.z));
    spawnStar();
    StartCoroutine(starWave());

}

public void spawnStar()
{
    Debug.Log("Yeah it works");

    star = Instantiate(point) as GameObject;
    star.transform.position = new Vector2(Random.Range(-screenBounds.x, screenBounds.x), Random.Range(-screenBounds.y, screenBounds.y));
}


IEnumerator starWave()
{
    while (true)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(respawnTime);
        Destroy(star);
        spawnStar();


    }
}
```

And the script on object prefab is

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col)
{


    if (col.gameObject.tag == "Player")
    {
        Debug.Log("this is star collider destory");
        Destroy(this.gameObject);
        





    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spawner script

```
public GameObject point;
void Start()
{
    spawnStar();
}

public void spawnStar()
{
    Debug.Log("Yeah it works");

    star = Instantiate(point) as GameObject;
}
```

Prefab script

```
// how long before our star moves
private timeBeforeMoving = 10f;

// our current time
private currentTimer = 0.0f;

// the screen size
private Vector2 screenBounds;  
   
void Start()
{
    screenBounds = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Screen.width, Screen.height, Camera.main.transform.position.z));
    transform.position = GenerateNewPosition();
}    

private void Update()
{
    // increase the time that has passed
    currentTimer += Time.deltaTime;
    
    // we have reached the timer threshold, so move the star
    if(currentTimer >= timeBeforeMoving)
    {
        MoveOurStar();
    }
}
    
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col)
{
    if (col.gameObject.tag == "Player")
    {
        MoveOurStar();
    }
}

private void MoveOurStar()
{
    // reset the timer as we just moved
    currentTimer = 0.0f;
    transform.position = GenerateNewPosition(); 
}

private Vector2 GenerateNewPosition()
{
    return new Vector2(Random.Range(-screenBounds.x, screenBounds.x), Random.Range(-screenBounds.y, screenBounds.y));; 
}
```

Instead of destroying it run your randomize position code again. If you do not want it spawning in the same location as the player, you can use a [circle cast](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.CircleCast.html) to determine if the new location the object will spawn is still on top of the player. If it is, just randomly pick a new location again.

If you do not want to put your spawn code inside of the star script when you create the star you can set a delegate callback in the star script to call back to the script that is spawning it letting it know it needs to be moved. Or make the spawner a [singleton](https://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/Singleton) or even implement an [eventsystem](https://medium.com/xrpractices/lets-build-a-custom-event-system-in-unity3d-d39f38b223d1) to fire an event when the object is destroyed letting the manager know to move that specific object.

If you would like to just go with the example code snippet I provided and are having trouble implementing the circle cast, let me know and I can provide another snippet.

Edit: I changed the code around a bit. Now the spawner will just spawn a single star and the star handles where it moves after it collides.

Comment: So i add this script on to the prefab and now it works but kind off , when i collide with the prefab the first time it respawn it but than it doesn't work the second time but works the third time

Comment: @JamalAhmad You do not need to use the whole snippet, almost everything is the same as what you had before. I just changed the line `Destroy(this.gameObject);` to `transform.position = new Vector2(Random.Range(-screenBounds.x, screenBounds.x), Random.Range(-screenBounds.y, screenBounds.y));`.

Comment: I did this. Now it spawn it when i collide with it but than it doesnt detect the collisiob 2nd time but than the repsawn timer runs out and it respawn a new one and collsion works again. I hope u understand me. In short it is not detecting the collision with obj that is in the OnTrigger2d fucntion

Comment: I also have the first script attached to an empty object and 2nd one attached to prefab

Comment: The first script just spawns new stars so that should not be the issue. If you do not want it to spawn more stars after the first one has spawned just do not call the coroutine. It is fine that the second script is on a prefab. The issue is if your SpriteRenderer or Image component is not attached to the same object as the script. If it is not, it will move where the collider is but not move the visual image of the star.

Comment: My sprit renderer is on prefab. Gameobject has nothing but the first script

Comment: When in the scene your Prefab objects are just GameObjects that are instances of the Prefab. Think of a Prefab as a blueprint for an object that you can duplicate forever to be new GameObjects. A Prefab is not an object, more the concept or idea of a GameObject that can be created. My question was if your Prefab had more objects in it, or if all the components (Collider and SpriteRenderer) are on it. And when you say that the collision works again after a new star is spawned, is that with all stars or jus the new spawned one?

Comment: okay So now i have this script on my gameobject in hierarchy https://pastebin.com/z8ftVqmL when it run it spawns the prefab on screen and i have this script on the prefab https://pastebin.com/Gg5FAt8c

Comment: Now when i run this and i collide with the object it changes its location because of the prefab script but than it doesn't change it again even though the collision is working.

Comment: @JamalAhmad The issue is your prefab does not have a Screen Height / Width. Calculate those values internally as I am guessing you added the Vector2 yourself which defaults to (0,0).

Comment: Bro let me just explain what i want to do because I have already wasted alot of your time. I want to spawn a prefab for a specific time lets say 10 seconds before it disappear and appears at a different location with a new timer but player just go and grab it than it should respawn without waiting all time as player have already touched it.

Comment: Thank you bro i added the  screenBounds = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Screen.width, Screen.height, Camera.main.transform.position.z)); and it now works. Any idea how can I add a timer on it?

Comment: Yea I can edit my answer. Just to confirm, you want a star that is in a location for X seconds, and if the player does not get to it, it will move. But if they do get to it, it moves too and resets the timer?

Comment: @JamalAhmad Updated the code. I did not change the spawner at all. I am running all of the logic inside of the prefab. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Its spawning like every frame with the speed of light. I think if(currentTimer <= timeBeforeMoving) is supposed to be >=

Comment: @JamalAhmad Sorry had flipped the <= to >=. Try the code now.